# How to zoom in and zoom out the size of icons on google maps?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to change the size of icon or marker on the google map while zooming in or zooming out? I am inspired by this link
http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/home/centerx:142.1/centery:41.1/zoom:19
and want to achieve some similar kind of thing. 
 Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a `zoom_changed`- event for a map, bind a function to it where you change the size of the marker(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you provided .. on zoom change  the icon/marker are hiding and are showed .. poligon for each vessel ... you should check for zoom change event and keep a list of releted object with marker and polygon. Based on zoom level you should toggle hiding and showing th geometry you need 
..

Anyway the icon marker don't change size .. but the polygon change because the related geometry is based on coords